# Castle Windsor - Get all classes derived from base class

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Sorry, I am new to Castle.Windsor, so this may be a noob question.

I have the following structure:

```
public class Device
{
...
}
public class Sensor : Device
{
...
}
public class Actuator : Device
{
...
}
```

I want to query Castle.Windsor for all components that inherit from Device...

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to query the container? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to use Castle.Windsor as a very simple plugin framework, beginning to think I would be better with MEF...

Comment: Do you want to let Windsor create a collection of _instances_ of subtypes of `Device`, or do you want to know which registrations exist in the Windsor container that inherit from `Device`?

Comment: Probably just which registrations exist, and then later I can create the instances as required.

Comment: But why do you need to know which registrations exist? That should usually be irrelevant. Just resolve the whole set and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
container.Register(Classes
    .FromAssemblyContaining<Device>()   
    .BasedOn<Device>()
    .WithServiceBase()
    .LifestyleTransient());
```